# Muscles twitching during non-workout activity

Tags: muscle

I've had periods in time where I'm just sitting in the office and all of the sudden one of triceps would start twitching like once per second or a bit more spread out. It doesn't hurt, but it's somewhat "annoying" cause it won't stop no matter what I do. I has happened to my triceps, my biceps, shoulders, and one of my legs. Not all together but those are the muscles were this has happened.

These "episodes" happen on a period at least 13 hours after my last workout. But I haven't found a relationship between the last workout and the muscle that twitches(If I do leg the day before, is not necessarily my leg that is twitching). Although they don't hurt, should I be concerned? Is it an intake deficit of something or just aftermath of previous workouts?

Comment: Potentially a medical based question rather than a physical fitness one? Could be linked to stress etc.

Comment: Well I doubt its medical, cause when I didn't workout it didn't happen @JJosaur

Comment: @JJosaur Kind of medical, yeah, but physical exertion is a known factor for the appearance of muscle twitches. It also can cause a shortage of electrolytes due to perspiration and high water intake during the workout, which might be the cause. It's the first and easiest thing to try to rule out.

Comment: Agreed, I just think you might get better answers from the medical boards than the phy fitness one.

Comment: @JJosaur Never checked those out. Good to know there's a place to refer people to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is most likely a *fasciculation* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasciculation), commonly known as a "muscle twitch". This is usually benign, but there can be more severe underlying conditions causing this. I know giving medical advice would be frowned upon here (especially by someone without a medical background) but we can't really go running to the doctor for every minor thing that can possibly be a symptom of something more severe, or you wouldn't ever get out of his/her office. So unless this is taking severe forms, lasts for a really long time, starts presenting itself with other weird symptoms or starts interfering with quality of life it's probably not something to be worried about.

Electrolyte imbalances are often indicated as a possible culprit for muscle issues such as cramps, spasms and twitches. Especially magnesium is singled out as a possible cause for such twitching. You could try taking a magnesium supplement if you don't have any medical issues counter-indicating this. Regular supplement quantities of something like magnesium citrate are safe and it's an over-the-counter substance. Or you could go for dietary sources rich in magnesium, such as seeds and nuts, cocoa, chives and bananas. If it's a simple lack of magnesium this could solve it. I take a magnesium supplement daily in the evening as I find it helps sleep. My sleep went to crap when I was on a ketogenic diet, and I got heart palpitations; a lack of electrolytes such as sodium, potassium and magnesium was most likely at least partially to blame for that, since things improved with higher intake.

Also, if you happen to consume quite a bit of caffeine (could be in pre-workouts too) you might wanna cut back a bit.

Comment: I'll give the magnesium supplement a go, and come back with results

Comment: @JustDoIt Make sure not to exceed recommended amounts; I trust if you have a medical history or any counter-indications you'll use your own proper judgement. Not trying to sound scary, it's just the regular "at your own responsibility" disclaimer before anyone crucifies me for suggesting anything more complex than water.

Comment: I'll ask my family doctor first, since I'm under hypothyroid medication

Comment: @JustDoIt That's a good call. With any medication and conditions present, you'll need a medical practitioner's opinion.

Comment: I have also seen excess acetylcholine leaking from either fatigued or otherwise compromised nerves being blamed, but unfortunately this is still something thst is not quite understokd yet.

Comment: Well, as I'm sitting here there's a twitch around my left elbow. I take a magnesium supplement daily, so I reckon at least a magnesium deficiency wouldn't be the only possible cause. Interesting to note: it seems to be the exact spot where I've had some pain for the past months due to a strain, which has nearly vanished through using straps on exercises requiring grip and an elbow sleeve for warmth. Maybe muscle repair or prior damage plays a role in the twitching as well.